# ffmpeg scale down video dynamically (squeeze-back) or zoompan out to smaller than original

Tags: animation, video, dynamic, ffmpeg, scale

I have 2 videos, I'm trying to overlay one on top of the other, and have it shrink down in an animated fashion until it appears like a picture-in-picture setup. Then, after a few seconds it should scale back up.

This is what I am trying to achieve (these would be **videos**, **not images**):
[image]

This is the closest I've been able to get, but, crucially, zoompanning "out" (as opposed to "in") does not appear to work; so, of course, this **does not work**:

`ffmpeg -i bg.mov -i top.mov -filter_complex "[0:v]zoompan=z='pzoom-0.1':d=1, setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[top]; [1:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+2/TB, scale=1920x1080, format=yuva420p,colorchannelmixer=aa=1.0[bottom]; [top][bottom]overlay=shortest=0" -vcodec libx264 out.mp4`

Is this achievable with ffmpeg?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the scale filter with animation, available since v4.3.

Here's something to get you started. This will expand the top layer from 480 px height to 1080 height in 2 seconds and then back to 480 px in 2 seconds.

`ffmpeg -i bg.mov -i top.mov -filter_complex "[0:v]scale=1920x1080,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[bg]; [1:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+2/TB, scale=-1:'480+600*abs(sin((t-2)*2*PI/8))':eval=frame[top]; [bg][top]overlay" -vcodec libx264 out.mp4`

Comment: Here's where I've gotten: ```ffmpeg -i bg.mov -i top.mov -filter_complex "[1:v]scale=1920x1080,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[bg]; [0:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=-1:'if(lte(t,2),ih,if(between(t,2,3),ih-ih*.475*abs(sin((t-2)*4*PI/8)),if(between(t,3,9),ih-ih*.475,if(lte(t,10),ih-ih*.475*abs(sin((t-2)*4*PI/8))))))':eval=frame[top]; [bg][top]overlay=y=(main_h-overlay_h)*.15" -vcodec libx264 out.mp4``` This is essentially doing exactly the behavior I want, with 1 exception: the `overlay y=(main_h-overlay_h)*.15` seems to make the animation a bit jittery, presumably due to rounding. Any way to fix this?

Comment: Would one of you be able to advise why you are using a formula abs(sin((t-2)*2*PI/8))? I don't have much background on video editing so any pointers on this topic helps.

Comment: @sivano I am using the sine function to achieve smooth animation. You could also just use a linear function of t without sine.

Comment: If I imagine the entire gif to be say bg.mov, is it possible to detect green and put top.mov in the green region?