# What ffmpeg filters can I use to achieve shrinking a video and keeping original aspect ratio?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-editing

I am trying to do some specific video editing with ffmpeg and am lacking the correct terminology to describe it (and thus read online how to achieve it). Can someone help describe this using standard (ffmpeg/video editing) terminology?

The below describes it verbosely, and you can see it visually at the end (this was done manually for one image).

I have a video with aspect ratio 1280x720. At some point in the video, I want to shrink the video diagonally (i.e. maintaining aspect ratio) so that it only takes up half the original width (i.e. 640) and then pad what is left with black. The purpose of this is to then overlay some other image on the left hand of the modified video.

**Before**
[image: Before]

**After**
[image: after]

Thank you

Comment: Is the downscaling instant or animated over time?

Comment: Preferably animated. I am currently looking at using the scale filter with animation, (available since v4.3 apparently) based on this question here:  

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62845459/ffmpeg-scale-down-video-dynamically-squeeze-back-or-zoompan-out-to-smaller-tha

Comment: Yes, that is what you will have to do.