# Scale image overlay over the time with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, huffman-code, android-ffmpeg

I have an overlay image and background video. I want to make the overlay 3 times bigger when 10 seconds of video pass, the scaling animation should take 1 second. Is it possible to do something like this with ffmpeg?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/62845459/ for a start.

Comment: That won't work with an image, already tried that one

Comment: You have to extend the length by adding e.g. `-loop 1 -t 10` before `-i image` to make a 10 second video stream out of the image.