# ffmpeg : how to use the animated scale filter?

Tags: ffmpeg

How do I animate a video layer from 1280x720 (full size) down to a PIP size, say 480x270 in the upper right corner over a duration of 1 second, remain that size for 10 seconds, and then resize back to 1280x720 over a duration of 1 second, and remain at that size for the remainder of the duration of the video?

I came across this: [ffmpeg scale down video dynamically (squeeze-back) or zoompan out to smaller than original](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62845459/ffmpeg-scale-down-video-dynamically-squeeze-back-or-zoompan-out-to-smaller-tha)

But the accepted answer doesn't give any info or point to any documentation on how it works or how to manipulate the variables.