# ffmpeg scale down video dynamically (squeeze-back) or zoompan out to smaller than original VER2

Tags: animation, video, dynamic, ffmpeg, scale

I have 2 videos, I'm trying to overlay one on top of the other, and have it shrink down in an animated fashion until it appears like a picture-in-picture setup. Then, after a few seconds it should scale back up. Just like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62845459/ffmpeg-scale-down-video-dynamically-squeeze-back-or-zoompan-out-to-smaller-tha) question. Here is the working code from there:

```
ffmpeg -i bg.mov -i top.mov -filter_complex "[0:v]scale=1920x1080,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[bg]; [1:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+2/TB, scale=-1:'480+600*abs(sin((t-2)*2*PI/8))':eval=frame[top]; [bg][top]overlay" -vcodec libx264 out.mp4
```

It works perfectly, but I have one difference I cannot achieve modifying existing code: scale filter in this example resizes the second video stream having attraction point in the top left corner of this stream. I mean, when the second stream is getting smaller, it is scaled to the top left corner. And if it is getting bigger, it again stretches from the top left corner. The top left corner of the stream being scaled is staying in one place constantly no matter what.

Is it possible to make more symmetrical version of this scale code, so when the second stream is scaled it is scaled from and to the top center of it (So the top left corner would move right when the stream is getting smaller and move to the left then the stream is getting bigger)?

[image]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because , as the ffmpeg tag states: Only questions about programmatic use of the FFmpeg libraries, API, or tools are on topic. Questions about interactive use of the command line tool should be asked on https://superuser.com/ or https://video.stackexchange.com/. Please delete this.

Comment: I am sorry, I just duplicated the original question not knowing it was placed in the wrong site.

Answer (score 1):

You have to modify the overlay co-ordinates.

overlay defaults to x=0 and y=0 which is where the top-left anchoring comes from.

Change to `[bg][top]overlay=x=(W-w)/2:y=0`

Comment: Thank you sir, you are really good at this! Now I have only one problem: the second stream oscillates terribly from left to right while being scaled, but I plan to deal with it with some smoothing function if I can find it lol

Comment: Looks like kinda scaling and overlaying occurring at the same time and they are fighting for the correct position each frame. I tried minterpolate=25 after the overlay with no luck, jitter still exists.